# How to read F(x) function from user input with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, mathjax

I have a problem when user input `f(x)` equation in TextBox for example:  `x^2 + 4x`

I set the value of `x` to `5` by replace every `x` in that TextBox so the program become `5^2 + 45`

The problem is when `4x` become `45`, it must be `4*5` in the program, but I have no idea how to change it, anyone know any JavaScript library for read `f(x)` equation?

NB:

I change `x` with function `fx.replace(/x/g,'5')` and
I'm using  JQuery, Mathjax Library for print `f(x)` from user input and ds3.js to create the diagram `f(x)` but not successful yet right now.

Comment: Before replacing `x`, try replacing `/(\d)\s*x/g` with `"$1 * x"`.

Comment: wow, it works, thanks buddy, but i`m still confused with RegEx things, what is $1 means ? and (\d)\s*x , why there is a '*' before x and \s , \s is a space character right?

Comment: Well, I sort of assumed you'd want `4 x` to be handled properly ;) So `(\d)` means "get a number and save it", `\s*` means "any number of spaces, including none of them", then you have the `x`. In the replacement, `$1` is the first "saved" thing (the number), then it's just `* x`.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this would be to add a '*' on user input if 'x' follows just numbers (example 4x , 34x etc)

fx.replace(/(\d+)x/g, "$1*x")

Comment: Presumably you would also need to account for `R = 5 + BX + (-X)`

Answer (score 0):

You might want to start with following imagining you take the user input and store it as a string. Your goal is to insert "*" sign regardless if it is 4x, 4y or 4z, whatever.

```
//THIS CODE MIGHT NEED SOME CORRECTION (NOT SURE) AND DEFINITELY NEEDS 
// TO BE REFACTORED AND IS HERE FOR ILLUSTRATION PURPOSE ONLY

var fx="x^2+4x";
var x=3; //LET'S ASSUME YOU HAVE THIS VALUE

eq_tokens=fx.split("")//eq_tokens=[x,^,2,+,4,x]
//Now since you have separated all the equations items,
// you can go forward and add * sign between 4 and x

var temp_item;
var new_eq_tokens=[];

for (item in eq_tokens){
    if eq_tokens.indexOf(item)==0||((eq_tokens.length)-1) {
       temp_item=item;
       new_eq_tokens.push(item);
       continue;
       }
    if parseInt(temp_item) && !parseInt(item) {
      if (item in ["+","-"...AND OTHER OPERATORS INCLUDING "."]) 
           {           
           new_eq_tokens.push(item);
           temp_item=item;
           }
      else {
          new_eq_tokens.push("*")
          new eq_tokens.push(item)
          }
    else {
        new_eq_tokens.push(item);
        temp_item=item;
        }
 }

// NOW YOUR NEW ARRAY WILL HAVE CORRESPONDING "*" IN YOUR CODE IF I DID NOT
// WRITE SOMETHING IN ERROR BUT YOU SHOULD GET THE GIST
// new_eq_tokens=["x","^","2","+","4","*","x"]

new_eq=new_eq_tokens.join("");
your_answer=eval(new_eq);
```

Remember, using eval leads to poor code optimization and makes your code vulnerable for injection attacks. Thus, validation is very important. But some of the issues that are associated with eval are often exaggerated more than that is really necessary. My recommendation is: Eval is really like money. EVAL IS A GREAT SLAVE IF YOU CAN TAME IT BUT TERRIBLE MASTER IF IT GETS WILD.